# Python - Read generic CSV (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

How can I read a file that ends with csv in a certain path?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\*.csv')
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you can find an answer at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013532/open-file-by-filename-wildcard)

Comment: What issue are you having? Maybe I'm not clear on what your question is. That would be a valid function to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it. Here is my answer.Use glob module and make a for/while loop of all the files.

```
import glob

listcsv=glob.glob('C:\Users\*.csv')
for i in listcsv:
    df=pd.read_csv(i)
```