# How can i send all excel files from a folder via outlook email

Tags: python, excel, email, outlook

Hi I want to make a script that sends some excel files stored in a folder one by one to a email address. But I seem to be getting an error.

```
Email_A = row['ICO Mail A']
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = Email_A
mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
mail.Body = 'Message body'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>HTML Message body</h2>' #this field is optional

# To attach a file to the email (optional):
attachment  = (r"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Work\Automation\SAP_output_scen1\*.xlsx")
for f in attachment:
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

mail.Send()



com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'File name or directory name is not valid.', None, 0, -2147024773), None)
```

Comment: Your attachment variable is just a string, and you do not do anything with the file f

Comment: You are using a wildcard pattern.  What you want is `attachment = glob.glob(r"C:\Users...\*.xlsx")`.

Comment: Tried glob and it gives me this: com_error: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, None)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not understand wildcards. It is your responsibility to expand wilcards and give `Attachments.Add` the actual filename. See [Open file by filename wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013532/open-file-by-filename-wildcard)